# Setting up a dashboard in JIRA: which gadget to use?

Tags: jira, dashboard

I'm trying to set up a dashboard in JIRA that will show me the open and the resolved items from the previous month. What would be a good gadget to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a custom search filter with the parameters you want, then use that filter in a gadget on your dashboard.

When logged in to JIRA, click on the "*Issues*" menu item at the top, select the "*Search for issues*" option from the dropdown, and finally click on the "*New filter*" button on the left.

- Click on the "*Status: All*" dropdown and select "*OPEN*" items only.
- Click on the "*More*" dropdown, select "*Resolution*" and then select "*Done*" items only.
- Click on the "*More*" dropdown again, select "*Created Date*" and enter the criteria (e.g. "*Within the last 4 weeks*").

Once you have completed these steps, click the "*Save as*" button at the top to save the filter. You can then click on "*Details*" > "*Edit permissions*" if you want to allow the filter to be used by others.

In the dashboard, you can use the "*Filter Results*" gadget that will bring up a table that uses your search filter. Just point to the name of the search filter you created in the "*Saved Filter*" field of the gadget.